# Is it possible to get the line number in the ejs errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, render, ejs

(Suppose) I have a *huge* ejs file containing JavaScript snippets. When I compile it, I get the following error:

> `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in mytemplate.ejs while compiling ejs`

While it's obvious there is a syntax error in my template, I can't know where the error is.

I have full access to the error object so, I was thinking if somewhere the error contains the line with the problem (in a similar way like the JavaScript engines tell you that there is a problem on a specific line).

I tried to access the `err.stack` field, but it only shows me the error origin (which comes from the ejs library), so that's not really helpful.

Is there a way to know where the syntax error is in the ejs file?

I'm using the [`ejs`](https://github.com/mde/ejs) package.

Comment: Can u console the err ?

Comment: @VishalKumarMitra Of course: `[SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) in mytemplate.ejs while compiling ejs]`

Comment: @IonicăBizău did you find out the issue for this? If so, can you please let me know? Even I got the same error.

Comment: @achuthakrishnan No... See if [this](https://github.com/mde/ejs/pull/129) helps... For syntax errors it there is no solution yet, from what I know.